# Google Cloud Server suddenly stopped working with 408 Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, server-error, request-timed-out

Google Cloud Server suddenly stopped working. Yesterday I got the error , " Error establishing database connection".

Today it is "Request Timeout
Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client"

Any suggestions to get over this issue??

Comment: This error probably means that you sent a request to your webserver. Your webserver sent a request to your database. The database did not reply before the webserver timed it out. You have not provided enough information to help you with the database timeout issue. I would start by looking at the logfiles for connection errors.

Comment: I checked the log. Nothing. There is a log that I restarted the instance. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen based on the configuration you have on your app.yaml. If the instances are overloaded you might encounter a 408 when trying to communicate with the server, in that case changing the scaling configuration on your yaml file might fix the issue.

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml) can help you with configuration of your yaml file, information with auto and manual scaling, healthcheck, readiness check etc.

And this [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability) would give you general information on how scaling work on App Engine and best practices.

Also, if you’re using WordPress, this is a common issue with WordPress